# Convert escaped Unicode character back to actual character

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, utf8-decode

I have the following value in a string variable in Java which has UTF-8 characters encoded like below

```
Dodd\u2013Frank
```

instead of

```
Dodd–Frank
```

(Assume that I don't have control over how this value is assigned to this string variable)

Now how do I convert (encode) it properly and store it back in a `String` variable?

I found the following code

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(str);
```

But this returns a `ByteBuffer`, but I want a `String` back.

**Edit**:

Some more additional information.

When I use `System.out.println(str);` I get

```
Dodd\u2013Frank
```

I am not sure what is the correct terminology (UTF-8 or unicode). Pardon me for that.

Comment: the question is unclear to me. When you `System.out.println(yourString);` do you see (1) `Dodd\u2013Frank` or (2) `Dodd–Frank` ?

Comment: Wrong, \u2013 is not an UTF-8 character, it is an escaped Unicode character. UTF-8 is a way of encoding UTF characters.

Comment: @jlordo and SirDarius I have updated the question with details.

Comment: Have a look at [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String))

Comment: Check the Apache Doc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Just wanted to understand, why not `"Dodd\u2013Frank".chars().forEach(a -> System.out.print((char) a));` ?

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` is deprecated, but moved to `commons-text` as `import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` which is not deprecated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try

```
str = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String))

Comment: If `Java` itself provides the functionality of parsing the value then why should we use any third party tool ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Then please explain how, because your answer definitly does not.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani in your own example, try `System.out.println(string);` before calling `getBytes();` and see what happens ;)

Comment: How come ? My answer solves the problem which is specified in the question asked, that convert unicode into readable string format.

Comment: @jlordo I have pasted that also you can check that this prints the perfect output, which I have taked from the console

Comment: @BhavikAmbani nope, when he prints out his string, he sees `Dodd\u2013Frank`, when we print your string we see `Dodd-Frank`. (before any conversion), his String is `"Dodd\\u2013Frank"`, your String is `"Dodd\u2013Frank"`

Comment: This might solve your issue in a simple case, but be careful.  If you are trying to use this solution, for example, on a JSON encoded string with UTF8 chars that you want unescaped, it will unescape things that you DONT want touched:  For example, if this String is inside a piece of JSON

"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e"

Comment: str = org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);

as commons.lang3 is deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

## `java.util.Properties`

You can take advantage of the fact that [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) supports strings with `\uXXXX` escape sequences and do something like this:

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new StringReader("key = " + yourInputString));
System.out.println("Escaped value: " + p.getProperty("key"));
```

Inelegant, but functional.

To handle the possible `IOExeception`, you may want a try-catch.

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
try { 
   p.load(new StringReader("key = " + input)); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
   e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Escaped value: " + p.getProperty("key"));
```

Comment: won't handle newlines

Comment: As written, true, though this solution could be applied to one line at a time.

Comment: Yeah, I am just warning people as I faced that. I actually replaced new lines with some special string, converted and converted back, worked like a charm, but not perfect for production code.

Comment: Works. Another approach is to read in one line at a time using a `BufferedReader` or `BufferedInputSteam` similar and apply this algorithm to one line at a time.

Answer (score 2):

try

> str = org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);

as org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a Unicode value, such as 00B0 (degree symbol, or superscript 'o', as in Spanish abbreviation for 'primero')

Here is a function that does just what you want:

```
public static String  unicodeToString( char  charValue )
{
    Character   ch = new Character( charValue );

    return ch.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml` to unescape the string loaded from an API that gives XML result.

Answer (score 0):

`UnicodeUnescaper` from `org.apache.commons:commons-text` is also acceptable.

`new UnicodeUnescaper().translate("Dodd\u2013Frank")`

Comment: `UnicodeUnescaper().translate(...)` needs a `writer` presumably a `StringWriter` - you may as well just use `import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` from `commons-text`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot add a dependency to your project, or you simply don't want to, here is a relatively simple implementation using a regular expression.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class UnicodeUnescape {

    private static final Pattern UNICODE_ESCAPE_PATTERN = 
            Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})");

    public static String unescape(String input) {
        return UNICODE_ESCAPE_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll(match -> {
            char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(match.group(1), 16);
            return Character.toString(c);
        });
    }

    private UnicodeUnescape() {}
}
```

Though this is obviously not the most efficient implementation. Also, this will **only** handle Unicode escape sequences, unlike [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) from *Apache Commons Text*.

Note that [`Matcher#replaceAll(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) was added in Java 9.

Remove `(?<!\\\\)` from the regex if literals like `\\u2013` should still be "unescaped" into `\–`.

---

Here's some very basic, non-exhaustive unit tests:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class UnicodeUnescapeTests {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Unicode sequence is unescaped")
    void testUnescape() {
        var unescaped = UnicodeUnescape.unescape("Dodd\\u2013Frank");
        assertEquals("Dodd–Frank", unescaped);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("surrogate pair is unescaped")
    void testUnescapeSurrogatePair() {
        var unescaped = UnicodeUnescape.unescape("Dodd Frank \\uD83C\\uDF09");
        assertEquals("Dodd Frank ", unescaped);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("escaped Unicode sequence is unchanged")
    void testEscapedUnicodeSequence() {
        var unescaped = UnicodeUnescape.unescape("Dodd\\\\u2013Frank");
        assertEquals("Dodd\\\\u2013Frank", unescaped);
    }
}
```

Output (from Gradle):

```
UnicodeUnescapeTests > escaped Unicode sequence is unchanged PASSED
UnicodeUnescapeTests > surrogate pair is unescaped PASSED
UnicodeUnescapeTests > Unicode sequence is unescaped PASSED
```

Answer (score -3):

You can convert that byte buffer to String like this :

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

public static CharsetDecoder decoder = CharsetDecoder.newDecoder();

public static String byteBufferToString(ByteBuffer buffer)
{
    String data = "";
    try 
    {
        // EDITOR'S NOTE -- There is no 'position' method for ByteBuffer.
        //                   As such, this is pseudocode.
        int old_position = buffer.position();
        data = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
        // reset buffer's position to its original so it is not altered:
        buffer.position(old_position);  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return data;
 }
```

Comment: decoder is object of CharsetDecoder class in java.nio package.Sorry to update that.See the edited answer.Thanks for reminding me.:)

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps the following solution which decodes the string correctly without any additional dependencies.

This works in a scala repl, though should work just as good in Java only solution.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.charset.Charset

> StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("Dodd\u2013Frank"))
res: java.nio.CharBuffer = Dodd–Frank
```

Comment: Tried this, but what is actually decoding the UTF-8 character is the fact that it is given directly in the String. What your example does, is to take a UTF-8 String, encode that, decode that, and - luckily - we get the same output as the input.

Comment: curious, what is a string example would fail to convert for this solution?

Comment: In the source "\u2013" is alread converted to the UTF-8 character. What would be a correct representation of the problem is "\\u2013" as the text to be converted contains the backslash and each character individually.