# MySQL insert and unicode characters

Tags: database, unicode, encoding, mysql

Here is sample code:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_unicode DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE test_unicode;

CREATE TABLE simple_table (text varchar(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO simple_table VALUES ('l\u2019agave');

SELECT * FROM simple_table;
```

And here is output:

```
+-------------+
| text        |
+-------------+
| lu2019agave |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Mysql stored my string without - " **\** "

I need to get "l\u2019agave" with - " **\** "

How I can do it?

I tried a lot of encoding settings to mysql, but it not working for me...

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO simple_table VALUES ('l\\u2019agave');
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working... but I got "l\u2019agave" from postgres (using pg_dump) and I will need to replace all strings in my dump... maybe there is exist other ways?

Comment: @AlexeyLisikhin you can try to use [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) `SET SESSION sql_mode=NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO `test_unicode`.`simple_table` (`text`) VALUES ('l\\u2019agave');
```

`This is because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”. To search for “\”, specify it as “\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against`.

Answer (score 0):

for java:
`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);`
from [Convert escaped Unicode character back to actual character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700333/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character#answer-13700590)