# Unknown characters displaying while encoding UTF-8 words into JSON format using json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a PHP file which takes UTF-8 (Malayalam) words from a MySQL database and displays it in a browser after encoding it into JSON. The MySQL database is in UTF-8 format. The database contains Malayalam words. When I try to display the words without converting it into JSON, it displays fine as Malayalam, whereas when I convert it into JSON using `json_encode` the Malayalam words are displayed as unknown characters, which I think is of ASCII format. I will show my PHP file and the code which I have used here:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name"); 
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
   { 
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
   } 
   $con->set_charset("utf8");

   $cresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM leaders"); 
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult)) {
      $rows[] = $r["name"];
      //This displays the names correctly in malayalam like this: പോള്‍ ജോസഫ്‌ 
      // etc in the browser
      //echo ($r["name"]);
   }
   $encoded= json_encode(array('Android' => $rows));
   //Converting to json displays the names as weird characters like this: 
   //  \u0d2a\u0d3f.\u0d35\u0d3f.\u0d2a\u0d4b\u0d33\u0d4d\u200d
   echo ($encoded);
   mysqli_close($con);
  ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I get Malayalam correctly as JSON? I need JSON because I need this JSON data sent to my client side (Android) for displaying it in my app. Please correct me if I'm going in the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON fully supports Unicode (rather should I say the standard for parsers does). The problem is that PHP does not fully support Unicode.

In [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding-is-utf-8-well-supported-by-browsers-or-should-i-use-nu), I'll quote

> Some frameworks, including PHP's implementation of JSON, always do the safe numeric encodings on the encoder side. This is intended for maximum compatibility with buggy/limited transport mechanisms and the like. However, this should not be interpreted as an indication that JSON decoders have problems with UTF-8.

Those "unknown characters" that you are referring to are actually known as [**Unicode Escape Sequences**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and are there for parsers built in programming languages that do not fully support Unicode. These sequences are also used in CSS files, for displaying Unicode characters (see [CSS content property](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)).

If you want to display this in your client side app (I'm going to assume you're using Java), then I'll refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700333/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character)

**tl;dr: There is nothing wrong with your JSON file. Those encodings are there to help the parser.**

Comment: I'm using android as client side.. I want to display it in android.. Please help me...

Comment: @TeeJay You're using Android as client side ... web? application? What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using php to implement the server side...