# java slugify string for non English characters

Tags: java, unicode, normalization, slug, unicode-normalization

I need to create slug strings(Human-readable URL slugs from any string) for English  and non English characters.. for example Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic and any other.

So, each string(for all languages) must be translated in English characters a-z, 0-9, for example `java-slugify-string-for-non-english-characters`

How can I achieve this in Java ?

Comment: do you mean that the strings should be ascii?

Comment: I mean that each string(for all languages) must be translated in English characters a-z, 0-9 only, for example java-slugify-string-for-non-english-characters

Comment: So, for "ログイン" which I got from the google.co.jp home page, what would you expect it to "slugify" to?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Slugify which is written in Java: https://github.com/slugify/slugify

Comment: I am not sure. The Slugify constructor accepts a Locale object so it may do.

Comment: I checked the code, the slugify library removes all non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 3):

Convert each character into its integer representation, and concatenate:

```
    String foo = "中国";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<foo.length(); i++) {
        result.append("\\").append((int)foo.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Produces:

> `"\20013\22269"`

...which is pretty easy to split and convert back to a string. You can also pad the numbers, convert them to hex, and add exclusions so that ASCII/English characters aren't converted, if you'd like. You could also have a look at [other, more stardard ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13700333/154066) of doing this sort of encoding.