# Converting HTML escape sequence to Java

Tags: android, json, rest

I am receiving a string using REST APIs.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
JSONArray contacts = obj.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject result = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
..
String brandName = result.getString("productName");
```

In some cases `productName` comes as `Dri-FIT&#8482; Element Half Zip`.

I want to show it as  "Dri-FIT™ Element Half Zip" in Android, but it shows up in the `TextView` as  `Dri-FIT&#8482; Element Half Zip`.

Can anyone help me as to how to convert the HTML escape sequence to a valid Java escape sequence so that I can view it?

Comment: Can you try the answers posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700333/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character

Comment: @GrabNewTech, no that answers for elements where I have \uHex number. But that is what I want. right now I am getting it in HTML form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I think this is the best way to show your special symbol.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Dri-FIT&#8482; Element Half Zip", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        }else{
            tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Dri-FIT&#8482; Element Half Zip"));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had used this sometime before, just couldn't remember that the `fromHtml` method existed.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace &#8482 to \u2122 (2122 is hex for 8482)

Comment: I think this is not what he wants. He want to change all symbols possible, not exactly this `™`.

Comment: Yeah. in general whenever I get a symbol